# How to create an "informative" preference

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences

I have created a PreferenceActivity.
Some of the preferences are pure informative. I want them to be a bit grayed out so it will be clear that clicking on them should not do anything.

How do i do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try to set its enabled attribute to false

```
<Preference android:enabled="false" ... />
```

Comment: it looks disabled. It is not exactly what i want

Answer (score 6):

```
style="?android:preferenceInformationStyle"
```

Comment: This is a much better approach than simply disabling the Preference. It will also apply the layout and future style attributes, which you can see under the style 'Preference.Information' at https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml

Comment: It works, however Android Studio Inspect code highlights it with the following warning: "Unknown attribute style". Do you know why?